# PHP/ MySQL Milliseconds to Hours:Minutes:Seconds

Tags: php, mysql, integer-overflow

I've been tasked with making a stats "viewer" for one of our server's gamemodes. Its been going great, but the only issue I have is converting the time played to hours:minutes:seconds.

The developer who made the actual gamemode stores the time played in MySQL in milliseconds. Sadly, many players have enough time to easily cause an integer overflow (when calculated in PHP).

Now, I'm wondering what is the easiest and most efficient way to resolve this. Is there a method to do this in the MySQL query that I am not aware of?

Comment: if you want to use mySQL  the DATE_FORMAT and SEC_TO_TIME functions will solve this

Comment: So I'm assuming I will have to divide the miliseconds by 1000 in order to use SEC_TO_TIME?

Comment: seems like  a sound assumption to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have 36001316000 milliseconds:

```
SET @miliseconds = 36001316000;
SET @s = @miliseconds / 1000; 
SET @hours = FLOOR(@s / 3600);
SET @minutes = FLOOR(@s / 60 - @hours * 60); 
SET @seconds = ROUND(@s - @hours * 3600 - @minutes * 60);

SELECT @hours, @minutes, @seconds;
```

this will return 10000 hours, 21 minutes & 56 seconds.

How will you store those information depends on how you will use it. If it's just for informational purpose, or PHP based calculations you can store it in varchar, if you need to do calculations in MySQL based on it, you can store it in 3 different integer fields.

Answer (score 0):

What is the column Type? Integer?

Changing integer to Unsigned Integer will double the max number.

The easy out:

Change table structure for that column from  `INT`  to `BIGINT`.

If already BIGINT, divide existing records by 1000 and use seconds.
Example:
Or divide existing records by 60000 and use minutes.

$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `time` = `time` / 60000";

Comment: The column type is BIGINT. Its irrelevant though, I just need to convert it to a user-friendly form.

Comment: You could use DECIMAL(254,0), the users will never live that many milliseconds.